# How does this program statically link to a .so in a non-default path

Tags: libraries, shared-library, dynamic-linking, ld

A program I am using can only be installed with a custom installer (IDA Freeware Demo). I have installed it in my home dir, it all works fine.

Now I noticed when checking the program with ldd: it ships with its own Qt libraries, which is places as shared libraries in its install dir (so the same directory its main executable file resides in, not /usr/lib or similar).

```
$ ldd ida64
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffec5fb9000)
    libida64.so => /home/asdf/idafree-7.0/./libida64.so 
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /home/asdf/idafree-7.0/./libQt5PrintSupport.so.5
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/asdf/idafree-7.0/./libQt5Widgets.so.5 
....
```

(install dir = /home/asdf/idafree-7.0/)

Now I wonder: How does it do that? I execute the program directly without any LD_LIB_PATH magic.

Comment: I guess the executable is hard coded to know where to look for "its own libraries".

Comment: How does that work?

Answer (score 2):

This is completely different from and unrelated to static linking. While I suppose a wrapper script  could modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH before launching the program, that's not what IDA does.

When a shared library is first linked from its constituent object files, a runtime path can be specified, i.e. the `--set-rpath` (short form `-r`) flag. This informs the loader to look in the named directory before looking elsewhere. The path may be hard coded, or it may use the `$ORIGIN` flag.

The `$ORIGIN` flag allows the loader to resolve the executable's current filepath, which in turn allows an rpath to more readily work from any directory.  IDA was likely just built with a flag such as `-Wl,-r,$ORIGIN`. If the Qt libraries had been in a subdirectory, it would just be `-Wl,-r,$ORIGIN/qtlibdir`.

There are also utilities that can edit this field after linking, such as patchelf.

All of this information may be found in the ld manual.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation how to run an executable requiring a unique LD_LIBRARY_PATH, e.g. a path to libs in the current directory/ :

Short : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` where the dot ( **.** ) means 'the current directory'

Usually also the system LD_LIBRARY_PATH will (have to) be included : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

"Hard coding" of e.g. `ida64` : The function in the executable to be run first is setting the unique LD_LIBRARY_PATH . ... Other example : `firefox` .

Comment: So unlike in windows, elf imports are resolved lazily?

Comment: I never use Windows©.  .... .... »»elf imports are resolved lazily«« : Please elaborate.

Comment: In windows, launching an executable fails if not all imports/libraries can be located by the loader before handing control to the executable. Here you say the linux executable itself can adjust LD_LIBRARY_PATH after its launch, so it would seem the loader only looks for and load those libraries when one of their exports is actually called. Correct?

Comment: The first call could be a "file.ini".  `ida64` may use `ida64.int` or something else. But usually the 'path' is part the code in the executable. If you open the executable `ida64` with an editor you will see a word like `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in plain text.